# Adding a virtual function to a sub-subclass without it being in the subclass?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

EDIT:
As DyP pointed in the comments below, this was only a typo in the function definition in c3(SoccerWorld).

- I have a class, say `c1`, which has a virtual function, `f`.
- Another class, `c2` inherits from `c1`, and another `c3` inherits from `c2`.
- `c2` doesn't have the virtual function `f`, but I want to add it to `c3` with some changes.
- The virtual function `f` in `c1` isn't pure, and is defined in `c1.cpp`. I still need `f` to be in `c1`, as well.

When adding `f` to `c3`, and not `c2`, I get an unresolved external symbol error. If I add `f` to `c2` as a virtual function as well, I get two errors: One the same as before, and another in `c1.obj` that says `f` already exists in `c3`.

This is what `c1`, `c2`, `c3` are like:

```
class C1 {
   virtual void f() { ... }
};

class C2 : public C1 {
   //No virtual f
};

class C3 : public C2 {
   virtual void f() { /*Do something*/ }
};
```

Real f function:

```
AbstractKart *World::createKart(const std::string &kart_ident, int index, int local_player_id, int global_player_id, RaceManager::KartType kart_type)
{ ... }
```

This is in class World. Class WorldWithRank inherits from World, and doesn't have the createKart function. Class SoccerWorld inherits from WorldWithRank and I want it to have createKart so that I place the karts differently if it's a SoccerWorld.

createKart is protected in World.

Error:

```
world.obj : error LNK2005: "protected: virtual class AbstractKart * __thiscall World::createKart(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int,int,int,enum RaceManager::KartType)" (?createKart@World@@MAEPAVAbstractKart@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@HHHW4KartType@RaceManager@@@Z) already defined in soccer_world.obj

soccer_world.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class AbstractKart * __thiscall SoccerWorld::createKart(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int,int,int,enum RaceManager::KartType)" (?createKart@SoccerWorld@@MAEPAVAbstractKart@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@HHHW4KartType@RaceManager@@@Z)
```

Comment: You can't skip levels with inheritance. That's why inheritance is described as an "is-a" relationship. If C2 is a C1 then it stands to reason that if C1 can do f(), then C2 can as well.

Comment: What is the visibility of f?

Comment: [Works for me.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8e67b8f2fb9e6ed7fc9e463350060556-9ed6f8a247f61e0c4190e1a7d58904c5). Show the real code, please, along with the errors.

Comment: Protected in c1.@Florian

Comment: @Borgleader Huh? So what if C2 doesn't override `C1::f`. It still can do `f()`. Not the design you see every day, but I don't see anything illegal about it.

Comment: @Yasin If `f()` is protected in C1, then you can't call it through a pointer to C1. But that doesn't explain undefined reference errors.

Comment: Your code works fine ([demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/y4z2so)).

Comment: @jrok OP said he didn't want C2 to have f() hence my comment. Or at least that was my understanding.

Comment: @Borgleader I see. I understood as that they just don't want to override in C2.

Comment: Yasin, could you please tell us where you put your code? (cpp files, headers etc), and provide a minimal complete example?

Comment: @DyP Both the soccerWorld and World headers and source files are in the same folder. Everything works fine with just World having the virtual function, until I try to add it to soccerWorld.

Comment: Guessing from your errors, I think you rather have some typos. It looks like in `soccer_world.cpp`, you defined a function `AbstractKart *World::createKart(...)` instead of `AbstractKart *SoccerWorld::createKart(...)`

Comment: @DyP, I did have that typo. Everything works now, my power of observation, or even thinking?, excluded. Thank you, and sorry if that wasted your time.

Comment: No problem. I hope this points the usefulness of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)s and complete examples / error info ;)

Comment: @DyP, Is there a way I can up-vote your comment?

Comment: @Yasin - Done it for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reposted from a comment to the OP:

Guessing from your errors, I think you rather have a typo. It looks like in `soccer_world.cpp`, you defined a function `AbstractKart *World::createKart(...)` instead of `AbstractKart *SoccerWorld::createKart(...)`.

This creates a second definition of `AbstractKart *World::createKart(...)`, which explains the first error:

> world.obj : error LNK2005: "`protected: virtual class AbstractKart * __thiscall World::createKart([...])`" [...] **already defined in soccer_world.obj**

The second error occurs if you try to call the not-defined `AbstractKart *SoccerWorld::createKart(...)`:

> soccer_world.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "`protected: virtual class AbstractKart * __thiscall SoccerWorld::createKart([...])`" [...]

Answer (score 1):

You could always define f() in class C2 as such:

```
class C2 : public C1 {

     virtual void f() { C1::f(); }

};
```

Which would allow C2 to function as if C3 never existed.

Comment: Still the same error persists: >c1.obj : error LNK2005: "protected: virtual class f already defined in c1.obj

Comment: Yeah, as jrok pointed out in the comments above, the desired functionality should be achieved without my code at all. Your above code concerning C1, C2, C3 works.  However, the actual linker error is probably unrelated to inheritance if I had to guess.